# PHP unset() selectively working

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I know there's a lot of these unset() problems on here, but this one is different. I'm trying to create an array that is a partial listing of a directory, with file names ".", "..", "feed.txt", and "index.php" removed. Here's the code:

```
var_dump($posts);
echo "this is arrayElementIsString(posts, file) before ->" . arrayElementIsString($posts, "index.php") . "<-
";
foreach($posts as $file) {
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "feed.txt" || $file == "index.php") {
        unset($posts[arrayElementIsString($posts, $file)]);
    }
}

echo "this is arrayElementIsString(posts, file) after ->" . arrayElementIsString($posts, "index.php") . "<-
";
var_dump($posts);
```

arrayElementIsString() is a function I wrote. It searches an array for a particular string and returns the index of that array element. Here it is:

```
function arrayElementIsString($array, $searchString) {
    for($i=0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        if((string)$array[$i] == $searchString) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output from this code:

```
    array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "."
  [1]=>
  string(2) ".."
  [2]=>
  string(20) "another-new-post.php"
  [3]=>
  string(8) "feed.txt"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "index.php"
  [5]=>
  string(17) "new-test-post.php"
}
this is arrayElementIsString(posts, file) before ->4<-
    this is arrayElementIsString(posts, file) after -><-
    array(3) {
  [2]=>
  string(20) "another-new-post.php"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "index.php"
  [5]=>
  string(17) "new-test-post.php"
}
```

The first var_dump shows the complete directory listing, the first in between line shows the index of "index.php", the next line shows the value having been unset, and the second var_dump shows "index.php" in the array still.

What I don't get is why this works for ., .., and feed.txt, but index.php is still listed after clearly being unset. I've tried moving the index.php file to the middle of the if statement to see if it would instead not unset one of the other files, but that didn't effect anything

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `arrayElementIsString` instead of passing the index in the loop?

Comment: @apokryfos My money's on temporary fit of insanity; or perhaps lack of coffee.

Comment: @deceze temporary? You're too kind

Comment: @Ethan May I interest you in an [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) instead of this monstrosity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing elements in an array inside a foreach-loop is a bad idea. Therefor you should instead setup a new array and do the following:

```
$newArray = array();
foreach($posts as $file) {
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "feed.txt" || $file == "index.php") {
        continue;
    }
    $newArray[] = $file;
}
```

Comment: Remove elements from an array is not a bad idea, I think the bad idea is using  `unset()` when there are dozens of functions to manage this arrays neededs.

Comment: It is a bad idea inside a foreach-loop. (Updated my post to reflect that)

Comment: PHP copies the array it iterates over so as long as you only unset things you've already iterated it shouldn't be much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($posts as $index => $file) {
    if($file == "." || $file == ".." || $file == "feed.txt" || $file == "index.php") {
        unset($posts[$index]);
    }
}
```

And delete `arrayElementIsString` forever.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```js
$posts = array([data_here]);

foreach($posts as $key => $value) {
  if(in_array($value, array('.', '..', 'index.php', 'feed.txt')) {
    unset($posts[$key]);
  }
}

// Re-index your keys incase you want to use for loop later and what not
$posts = array_values($posts);
```